# Generate memory dump for a windows service that stops unexpectedly

Tags: windows, windows-services, windbg, memory-dump

How do I generate a memory dump for a windows service that stops unexpectedly?

Comment: Depending on what is stopping the service, a good place to start would be either setting up [Windows Error Reporting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb513638%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the dump for you, or attaching [DebugDiag](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42933).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1) Download [ProcDump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx)

2) At an admin command prompt, in the same directory as procdump, type this:

```
procdump -ma -e <serviceprocessname>.exe
```

3) Wait for crash and dump will be generated

Comment: If the service stopped process will not be running right? Then how can you take a dump? Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes you're missing the part where you attach the debugger before the process crashes, so when it goes down, the debugger captures the dump.